# Unity Dash extremely laggy

Tags: unity, performance

I'm running 12.04 64bit. I've been running gnome shell for a while and decided to give Unity a try. I logged out and back in with the Unity Shell selected.

I noticed that, sometimes when I press the super key, the dash takes about 0.5 to 1 second to open and it is extremely slow while searching/typing in it.

I'm guessing gnome-shell messed something up.

Also, another minor issue is when I right-click the desktop and click "Change desktop wallpaper", it simply opens the system settings, not any wallpaper options.

What's going on?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably post this as two separate questions.

My super-key has a delay but it doesn't sound like it's as slow as yours.

There seem to be some animations that run when opening and moving through the dash.  Depending on your machine's resources these could be causing the delay.  I think you can remove the animations through compiz config settings manager.  Personally, I don't like mucking around with compiz so I just enjoy the minor exercise in patience when opening the dash.

Don't know about the wallpaper issue - never seen that before.